# Replicate Nginx proxy_pass on NodeJs + Express

Tags: node.js, express, proxy

If you do this in Nginx:

```
location /apiproxy/ {
    proxy_pass                      https://apidev.site.com/;
}
```

All request to domain.com/apiproxy/* will be passed to apidev.site.com/*, so domain.com/apiproxy/foo/bar/ will be passed to apidev.site.com/foo/bar.

Im trying to replicate the same behavior in NodeJS with express and [proxy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-http-proxy), according to documentation:

```
app.use('/apiproxy/*', proxy('https://apidev.site.com/v1', {
    proxyReqPathResolver: function(req) {
        console.log(require('url').parse(req.url).path);
        return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
    }}));
```

But that loose everithing after /apriproxy/. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont know if you have tried this, but if you do not add *. then it passes the url.

Example

```
app.use('/proxy', proxy('http://google.com', {
  proxyReqPathResolver: function (req) {
    console.log(require('url').parse(req.url).path);
    return require('url').parse(req.url).path;
  }
}));
```

If we call `/proxy/abc`, then it calls `http://google.com/abc`